# What is the shortcut of commenting multiple lines in Smartface?

Tags: smartface.io

commenting multiple lines on Smartface is very tiring,

is there any way to comment multiple lines easily on Smartface IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + K helps you to commenting or uncommenting multiple lines of codes.

Answer (score -1):

you are very funny. Smartface asks the shortcut of it. :)

Hey smartface, you cannot have known the use of /* */ notation